# How to Hide Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to hide bootstrap-datepicker but its not hiding.

I've already tried theese.

```
$('#from').datepicker('hide');
$('#from').datepicker('remove');
$('#from').datepicker('close');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#from").datepicker("destroy");` should do the trick. Would be good to see in what context you are doing this. e.g. complete jQuery and HTML code that shows the basics of what you are doing.